# fa fa spinner when the button reads Loading

Tags: javascript, html, css

How to insert a fa fa spinner when the button reads Loading ...

`Start` button is `disabled` before loading the document, when the document is loaded the button is enable, and when you click on `Start`, the Start changes to `Loading ...` and in front of `Loading` inside the button should be a `fa fa spinner`.

I tried in several ways but I failed and I ask your for a little help, thanks!

```
<input type="submit" id="submitButton" name="b1" value="Start" 
disabled onclick="javascript:document.MyForm.b1.value='Loading...'" />
```

Comment: So append an element to the page?

Comment: How to do it, I don't know what you mean specifically, can you show me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

a pure Javascript can do it , this is a sample  :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
</head>
<body>

    <input type="submit" id="submitButton" name="b1" value="Start" onclick="submitClicked()" />

    <i class="fa fa-refresh fa-spin loading-spinner" class="" style="font-size:24px"></i>


    <script>
        function toggleLoading(isLoading) {
            let btn = document.querySelector("#submitButton")
            btn.innerText = isLoading ? 'Loading...' : 'Start';
            document.querySelector(".loading-spinner").style.display = isLoading ? "inline-block" : 'none';
        }


        function submitClicked(){
            // do form submit here
            toggleLoading(true);
        }


        toggleLoading(false)
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

check this code Pen [Here](https://codepen.io/zydtekcz/pen/GRmMpob)

Comment: Thanks but this is not a good solution, the first thing you see in my tag is disabled, which means that the `Start` button is `disabled` before loading the document, when the document is loaded the button is enable, and when you click on `Start`, the Start changes to `Loading ...` and in front of `Loading` inside the button should be a `fa fa spinner`.

Comment: I updated the Code pen code, see if that what you want

Comment: Thank you very much, but your solution is not good for me.